# Validacion, Filtrar resultados en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos dias, Tengo un query que retorna valores de varias funciones y necesito filtrarlo con otra tabla B ya que no quiero que muestre el registro si existe en la tabla B
Este es el query que quiero filtrar

```
 SELECT FormaPago, NDCH, CORE, FechaPago, MontoReclamo,
 MontoIndemnizado, ImpuestoRetenido, ProntoPago, TotalPago, Deposito,
 FDeposito, NBanco, MIVA
 FROM dbo.fn_getPagosAgrupadosPrev('1', '1', '0001')
 ORDER BY FechaPago DESC
```

Este es el resultado de este query

```
FormaPago   NDCH    CORE    FechaPago   MontoReclamo    MontoIndemnizado    ImpuestoRetenido    ProntoPago  TotalPago   Deposito    FDeposito   NBanco  MIVA 
CHEQUE  47900005279 13257   2018-07-23  337.60           337.60               -16.88                0.00      320.72    0          00/00/0000   NULL     0.00
CHEQUE  47900019987 1323    2017-04-10  4703.87          4303.87             -154.59                  0.00       4149.28    0          00/00/0000   NULL    0.00
TRANSF  3751       13796162 2016-11-18  2410876.04      1200000.00          -48489.44             0.00      1151510.56  0         00/00/0000    NULL    0.00
TRANSF  3751       13801093 2016-11-18  186659.16       6659.16                  0.00                 0.00        6659.16   0         00/00/0000    NULL    0.00
```

y necesito decirle que si el CORE existe en la tabla B que no muestre los resultados

```
select * from hd3928 WHERE CORE28 = 1323
```

He intentado usar un INNER JOIN pero no funciona debidamente

```
SELECT FormaPago, NDCH, CORE, FechaPago, MontoReclamo, MontoIndemnizado, ImpuestoRetenido, ProntoPago, TotalPago, Deposito, FDeposito, NBanco,  
MIVA
FROM dbo.fn_getPagosAgrupadosPrev('1', '1', '0001') 
INNER JOIN hd3928
ON CORE != CORE28 
ORDER BY FechaPago DESC
```

El resultado que esto trae es

```
FormaPago   NDCH    CORE    FechaPago   MontoReclamo    MontoIndemnizado    ImpuestoRetenido    ProntoPago  TotalPago   Deposito    FDeposito   NBanco  MIVA 
CHEQUE  47900005279 13257   2018-07-23  337.60           337.60               -16.88                0.00      320.72    0          00/00/0000   NULL     0.00
CHEQUE  47900005279 13257   2018-07-23  337.60           337.60               -16.88                0.00      320.72    0          00/00/0000   NULL     0.00
CHEQUE  47900019987 1323    2017-04-10  4703.87          4303.87             -154.59                  0.00       4149.28    0          00/00/0000   NULL    0.00
CHEQUE  47900019987 1323    2017-04-10  4703.87          4303.87             -154.59                  0.00       4149.28    0          00/00/0000   NULL    0.00
```

y el resultado deseado es quitar el registro donde CORE = 1323

```
FormaPago   NDCH    CORE    FechaPago   MontoReclamo    MontoIndemnizado    ImpuestoRetenido    ProntoPago  TotalPago   Deposito    FDeposito   NBanco  MIVA 
CHEQUE  47900005279 13257   2018-07-23  337.60           337.60               -16.88                0.00      320.72    0          00/00/0000   NULL     0.00
TRANSF  3751       13796162 2016-11-18  2410876.04      1200000.00          -48489.44             0.00      1151510.56  0         00/00/0000    NULL    0.00
TRANSF  3751       13801093 2016-11-18  186659.16       6659.16                  0.00                 0.00        6659.16   0         00/00/0000    NULL    0.00
```

Hay otra forma que lo pudiera hacer?

Comment: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otra opción

```
SELECT FormaPago, NDCH, CORE, FechaPago, MontoReclamo,
 MontoIndemnizado, ImpuestoRetenido, ProntoPago, TotalPago, Deposito,
 FDeposito, NBanco, MIVA
FROM dbo.fn_getPagosAgrupadosPrev('1', '1', '0001') t
 where not exists(select top 1 null from hd3928 WHERE CORE28 = t.CORE)
ORDER BY FechaPago DESC
```

Comment: Lo estoy intentando con el null pero me dice "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'null'."

Comment: @Carlos: Si quitas el `TOP` en frente del `null` va a funcionar bien. Me imagino que pusistes el `TOP` para optimizar, pero no es necesario, ya que con un `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, SQL Server automáticamente va a parar de buscar los registros despues que encuentre uno.

Comment: si asi es, olvide poner el 1

Comment: Pero ¿para qué usar `TOP`?

Comment: es solo costumbre antes sql 2000  para optimizar el query se le colocaba, ahora en el plan de ejecución es lo mismo a que pongas *, va a parar cuando encuentre un registro

Comment: @CarlosCocom Quitó ese registro pero hay otros tambien que no se muestran, en la consulta sin la validacion hay 15611 registros pero ahora con las validacioens muestra 15584

Comment: @Hans Recuerda sql trabaja con sets. La consulta se traduce muestrame lo que hay en fn...prev que no existe en hd3928 usando el key {core =core28} ahora si solo quieres ocultar información referente al registro 1323 en where deberia ir "where CORE <> 1323" en lugar del "not exist.."

Comment: @CarlosCocom Ya esta resuelto! Muchas Gracias... Con el primer query que escribiste estaba resuelto, yo tenia la mente cerrada a los resultados limitandome con un solo registro que use de ejemplo mientras que el query lo hacia para todos los casos

Answer (score 2):

Podrias utilizar la clausula `WHERE`, filtrando solo aquellos que no tienen un registro relacionado en la tabla `IVRDB2.S103V5HM.UNHC02.hd3928`. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT FormaPago, NDCH, CORE, FechaPago, MontoReclamo, MontoIndemnizado,
  ImpuestoRetenido, ProntoPago, TotalPago, Deposito, FDeposito, NBanco,
  MIVA
FROM dbo.fn_getPagosAgrupadosPrev('1', '1', '0001') 
WHERE CORE NOT IN (SELECT CORE28 FROM IVRDB2.S103V5HM.UNHC02.hd3928)
ORDER BY FechaPago DESC
```

Comment: Pero esto me traeria tambien los registros que estan dentro del IVRDB2.S103V5HM.UNHC02.hd3928 cierto?

Comment: @Hans: No, la respuesta de Marcos debería funcionar correctamente también, al igual que la de Carlos.

Comment: @sstan los dos estan funcionando, estoy validando ahora si esta correcto porque no los ordena bien

Comment: @Hans, si `CORE28` puede repetirse (no es un valor único) para optimizar la sub-consulta, se puede agregar `DISTINCT`. Aguardo tu comentario para actualizar mi respuesta. PD: gracias @sstan.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Quitó ese registro pero hay otros tambien que no se muestran, en la consulta sin la validacion hay 15611 registros pero ahora con las validacioens muestra 15584

Comment: @Hans, no entendí que me quisiste decir. ¿Hay 15611 haciendo la consulta **sin** el `WHERE` y 15584 **con** el `WHERE`? si es así, quiere decir que solo hay 27 registros con `CORE = CORE28`

Comment: @MarcosGallardo exacto solo que si hago el Where buscando cuantos registros contiene el numero de CORE me dice que hay uno solo

Comment: @Hans, ademas estas necesitando hacer **otra consulta** para saber cuantos registros  son? Por favor tomate el tiempo que necesites y escribe un comentario explicando mejor cual es el problema y el resultado esperado o bien [edita tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/35718/edit) incluyendo esta nueva información.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Ya esta resuelto! Muchas Gracias

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Con el primer query que escribiste estaba resuelto, yo tenia la mente cerrada a los resultados limitandome con un solo registro que use de ejemplo mientras que el query lo hacia para todos los casos

Answer (score 0):

deberias usar un Left join en lugar de InnerJoin

```
SELECT FormaPago, NDCH, CORE, FechaPago, MontoReclamo, MontoIndemnizado, ImpuestoRetenido, ProntoPago, TotalPago, Deposito, FDeposito, NBanco,  
MIVA
FROM dbo.fn_getPagosAgrupadosPrev('1', '1', '0001') 
**LEFT** JOIN IVRDB2.S103V5HM.UNHC02.hd3928
ON CORE != CORE28 
ORDER BY FechaPago DESC
```

Comment: Con el left join me sigue duplicando los registros